# How to set an image in imageview swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uiimageview

So I have an image view titled cashOrCredit and have am trying to set it's image programatically but somehow not able to.

First I set the image like this

```
cell.cashOrCredit.image = UIImage(named: "cash1.png")
```

and I get an error saying a separator of "," is needed.

Then I tried it this way

```
var cashImage: UIImage?
cashImage = "cash1.png"
cell.cashOrCredit.image = cashImage
```

But I get a THREAD 1 EXC BAD INSTRUCTION error.
I can't seem to understand what is going wrong ?

Here is the error

[image: 1]

Comment: If `cashOrCredit` is an IBOutlet you should verify that it is correctly connected in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Updated for Swift 3:

use below simple code, to set the image to UIImageView;

```
class YourViewControllerName: UIViewController {

        var mYourImageViewOutlet: UIImageView?

        func addImageToUIImageView{
            var yourImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Birthday_logo")!
            mYourImageViewOutlet.image = yourImage
        } // call this function where you want to set image.
     }
```

Note: "Birthday_logo" type of image must be present in your Assets.xcassets of your project.
I attached the screenshot if you want any help please refer it.

****// used anywhere you want to add an image to UIImageView. [Here I used one function & in that function, I write a code to set image to UIImageView]****

Enjoy..![image]

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
cell.cashOrCredit.image = UIImage(named: "cash1")
```

and check "cash1.png" image is available in Assets.xcassets or not.

If you get solution, then give upvote to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Delete ".png":

```
cell.cashOrCredit.image = UIImage(named: "cash1")
```

You can also set it all programmatically:

```
let cellImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT))
cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "cash1")
cell.addSubview(cellImage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take Outlet of ImageView

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgProfile: UIImageView!
```

Go through the following code which contains will be helpful you to pick image or capture image from the camera.

```
func choosePicker() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select Option", message: nil, preferredStyle: (IS_IPAD ? UIAlertControllerStyle.alert : UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet))
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { action -> Void in
        })
        let gallery = UIAlertAction(title: "From Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default
            , handler: { action -> Void in
                self.openPicker(isCamera: false)
        })
        let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default
            , handler: { action -> Void in
                self.openPicker(isCamera: true)
        })
        alertController.addAction(gallery)
        alertController.addAction(camera)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func openPicker(isCamera : Bool) {
        let picker:UIImagePickerController?=UIImagePickerController()
        if isCamera {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        } else {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            picker!.allowsEditing = true
        }
        picker?.delegate = self

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            self.present(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            picker!.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            present(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)//4
            picker!.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = imgProfile
            picker!.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
        }
    }

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.imgProfile.image = image
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Call **choosePicker** method wherever you want to call.

Answer (score 1):

Check if cashOrCredit is uiimageview.

Secondly,

cashImage = UIImage(named: "cash1.png")

If that doesnot work, try

cell?. cashOrCredit.image

check if cell is nil?

In the context of Swift code, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION usually means you’ve hit a compiler trap, that is, an undefined instruction inserted into the code by the compiler because of a bug detected at runtime.  The most common cause of these are:

1. failure to unwrap an optional — This can be a forced unwrap (!) or an implicit unwrap (accessing an implicitly unwrapped optional that’s nil).
2. array out of bounds
3. a failed forced cast (as!), either because the value was a nil optional or because the value was of the wrong type

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var cashOrCredit: UIImageView! This is how the cashOrCredit is defined

Comment: @A.G did you put the image in assets folder as an image set?? Or just drag to your project??

Comment: Even if you misspelled the image name, its not going to crash your program.
I think the error is somewhere else.
Can you post the debug error??

Comment: I tried both ways but it still gives me the same error

Comment: @A.G could u show me the error in the debug??.
Pic or something??

Comment: I can't show you a picture because I can't put it on a stack overflow comment.

Comment: Edit your question with pic. Can yiu tell the error code after BAD INSTRUCTION.??

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @A.G hey, try ? After cell.
cell?.cashOrCredit.image

Comment: @A.G i think the cell is nil.